# Python: How to replace "datetime" in a Dataframe with only the Day represented as integer value?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, dataframe, integer, transform

I am dealing with a dataframe called "Data" containing two columns, one is the userid, the other one a datetime object:

```
userid | eventTime 
1      | 2018-11-01 07:36:58
2      | 2018-11-07 08:04:12
..     | ....
```

My goal is now to replace the entry in this dataframe column eventTime with just the number of the day in the specific month as integer value, e.g. the first day (=1) in November and the seventh day (=7) in November.

So the Result shall be

```
userid | eventTime 
1      | 1
2      | 7
..     | ....
```

How can I get this done?

I already extracted indices from the data frame and tried to modify it in a loop but I don't know how it shall work:

```
temp = Data.index.get_values()  #get indices from data frame

for temp, row in Data.iterrows():
    print(row['eventTime'])
```

Comment: Are you asking us how to do `datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1).day`? If so, a really good way to not ask questions but find it what a object contains on your own is to do `print(dir(variable))`. In this case you'd see clear as day that you can do `.day` or `.year` for a datetime object.

Comment: Hi @Torxed, i first transformed the data from string to a datetime object `Data["eventTime"] = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in Data["eventTime"]]` and unfortunately i dont know how to extract only the day from it. That is really my question......

Comment: `Data["eventTime"][0].day` by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
                        'eventTime': [datetime(2000, 1, 1),
                                      datetime(2000, 2, 2),
                                      datetime(2000, 3, 3),
                                      datetime(2000, 4, 4)]})
print(df)
#    eventTime user
# 0 2000-01-01    a
# 1 2000-02-02    b
# 2 2000-03-03    a
# 3 2000-04-04    b
```

You can operate on a particular column with the [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method, and `datetime` objects provide a [`datetime.day`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.day) property that gives you the day of the month as an integer:

```
df['day'] = df.eventTime.apply(lambda x: x.day)
print(df)
#    eventTime user  day
# 0 2000-01-01    a    1
# 1 2000-02-02    b    2
# 2 2000-03-03    a    3
# 3 2000-04-04    b    4
```

If you want to replace the `eventTime` column instead of create a new column, just use:

```
df['eventTime'] = df.eventTime.apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

Comment: @john thanks! Check out Arran Duff's answer too. I think his way is a little clearer and probably faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['eventTime'] = df['eventTime'].dt.day
```

Should work - assuming **df** is your dataframe
Performing a vector operation like this is the most efficient way to work on a dataframe

Comment: Better than my answer. I keep forgetting you can do `df.column.dt` or `df.column.str` type of operations!